# Packet Sniffing from a BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to develop an app that does basic packet sniffing. So, I would like to know if packet sniffing is feasible from a BlackBerry.

Comment: I see you also asked on the official blackberry forums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Is-Packet-Sniffing-possible-in-Blackberry/m-p/637539 . Do you want to sniff e.g. WiFi Traffic? Or do you want to sniff the Blackberry traffic with e.g. the E-Mail Server? Let me tell you right away: Not possible. Blackberry's data connections are encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  The most you can do is keep track of the number of packets sent and received over the radio, but not see the actual contents.  See [RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getNumberOfPacketsReceived%28%29) and [RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getNumberOfPacketsSent%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged "blackberry simulator"  are you looking for an app in to observe what the simulator is doing or for an app in real world mode?

Intercepting things going in and out of the sim is not to hard, especially if you acted as some kind of intermediary pipe between the bbsim and the mds-cs sim.

Packet sniffing on device though i do not believe is possible at all, except over wifi from a promiscuous node laptop sniffing next to it.